# Правильное использование полиморфизма в java

Tags: java

Существует очень простой класс, описывающий узел дерева:

```
public class TreeNode<T> {
    public Set<TreeNode<T>> children = new HashSet<>();
    public T value;
}
```

Есть его класс-наследник, который отличается наличием ссылки на родителя:

```
public class DoubleLinkedTreeNode<T> extends TreeNode<T> {
    public DoubleLinkedTreeNode<T> parent;
}
```

При этом хочется, чтобы класс-наследник принимал в качестве детей только экземпляры этого же класса. Я могу повторно объявить поле children с новым generic-типом, однако это просто скроет его, и, конечно, не является желаемым решением задачи. Как мне правильно организовать такой класс-наследник, который будет оперировать только новым типом? На ум приходит только введение еще одного generic-типа, но это настолько же хорошее решение, как и скрытие поля.

Comment: А почему бы вам не использовать только один тип для всех узлов? Для чего это разделение?

Comment: @Yatajga вообще это premature optimization, но эти сущности будут использоваться в довольно нагруженных местах, поэтому хочется сэкономить там, где это не нужно.

Comment: Я думал, найдётся решение, эмулирующее миксины при помощи default interface implementation. Может сработать, кстати. Но пока не вкурю, как именно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В рамках выбранной вами иерархии типов невозможно.

Действительно, если бы даже можно было сделать как вы хотите, то всегда можно было бы закастить `DoubleLinkedTreeNode<T>` в `TreeNode<T>`, и вставить в него другой `TreeNode<T>`.

Какой возможен выход?

- В языках с более сложной системой типов вы сможете выразить отношение «добавить объект типа, равного собственному». Например, функциональные языки обычно умеют подобное. Учтите, что при этом у вас не будет наследования.
- Некоторые языки поддерживают mixin'ы. Для JVM это, например, Scala. При помощи mixin'ов вашу семантику, кажется, можно выразить.
- Откажитесь от наследования и общего предка. Для того, чтобы избежать повторения кода, воспользуйтесь метапрограммированием. Хоть бы и «ручной» (то есть, при помощи скрипта) генерацией кода во время компиляции!